# Get intersection in data.frame of some variables without omitting others

Tags: r, dplyr, intersect

I have a huge dataframe (15 million rows), e.g.

```
    data = data.frame(
       human = c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1),
       hair = c(3,1,5,3,1,1,3,4,4,5,5),
       eye_colour = c(1,4,2,1,4,3,1,3,3,3),
       fuel = c(1,2,3,3,4,7,5,6,1,4,6)
    )
```

and I want to find the intersection for    `human` being 0 and 1 of    `hair` and    `eye_colour` (so only if    `hair` and    `eye_colour` are the same for at least    `human==0` and    `human==1`, I want to keep the row) and mark it with a    `cyclon_individual`. So for my application one    `cyclon_individual` is somebody, who is at least once recorded as    `human==1` and    `human==0` and has same    `hair` and    `eye_colour` coding, i.e. the following result:

```
    cyclon_individual human hair eye_colour fuel
    1                 1     3    1          1
    1                 1     3    1          3
    1                 0     3    1          5
    2                 0     1    4          2
    2                 1     1    4          4
```

I think, I have taken an awkward way, and yet I haven't found a clever way to code the    `cyclon_individual` with    `dplyr`:

```
    require('dplyr')
    hum = subset(data, human == 1)
    non_hum = subset(data, human == 0)
    feature_intersection = c("hair", "eye_colour")

    cyclon = intersect(hum[,feature_intersection],non_hum[,feature_intersection])
    cyclon_data = cyclon %>%
                    rowwise() %>%
                    do(filter(data,hair==.$hair,eye_colour==.$eye_colour))
```

So is there a more direct way to get to    `cyclon_data`, since the current coding will take at least 26h? 
And is there a clever way to include the variable    `cyclon_individual` without using a loop by going through all rows of    `cyclon`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply group by hair and eye_color and keep the ones where human has both 0 and 1, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
 group_by(hair, eye_colour) %>% 
 filter(length(unique(human)) > 1)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 4
> # Groups:   hair, eye_colour [2]
>   human  hair eye_colour  fuel
>   <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
> 1     1     3          1     1
> 2     0     1          4     2
> 3     1     3          1     3
> 4     1     1          4     4
> 5     0     3          1     5
> ```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `n_distinct` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(hair, eye_color) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(human) > 1)
```